# How can I show that a function is always not commutative

Tags: math, proof

I have the following vexing problem.
I have implemented the following function:

```
function bool less(nat x, nat y) {
    if (y<>0) then
       if (x<>0) then
           return less(x-1,y-1);
       else
           return true;
       end;
    else
       return false;
    end;
end;
```

How can I show that for all x,y the following
less(x,y) and less(y,x) are not possible at the 
same time?

Bye

Comment: Is that supposed to be in a particular programming language?  It depends on the exact semantics, then.  If it's supposed to be a generic algorithm, why the programming-looking details?

Comment: If `x` and `y` are both negative, your recursion doesn't terminate.

Comment: x and y are supposed to be nat. So their range should be 0...max. But you can also view the problem posed for range 0...inf, this makes it eventually simpler.

Comment: The programming looking details are here because my original mathematical posed question was refused to be out of scope of a forum for programming related questions. But of course I am interested in computations, otherwise I wouldn't pose the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all I would ask you to consider the case of `less(-1, -2)`, so we will have to define the function to be on the bounds of n ≥ 0. Also when the first input is equal to the second it will return true for both orderings, so we will have to assume that x ≠ y.

I would use Proof by Contradiction.

Assume that for some x and some y where x and y are both ≥ 0 and x≠y, that less(x,y) and less(y,x) are both true.

This would imply that while x and y are both nonzero, you subtract one from them n times until one of them is zero, checking x first. The function returns true when the first operand reaches zero, false when the second operand reaches zero while the first is nonzero.

There are two cases for this:

1. x reaches zero first. In this case n = x, because 0 = x - n(1).
2. y reaches zero first. In this case n = y, because 0 = y - n(1).

By our assumption, less(x,y) returned true, meaning that the function iterated x times, after which x - x(1) = 0 and y - x(1) > 0 (because y ≠ x, and the function didn't return false before hand).

Similarly, less(y,x) returned true, meaning that the function iterated y times, after which y- y(1) = 0 and x - y(1) > 0 (same reasons as before).

This gives us two useful relations: `y - x > 0` and `x - y > 0`. rearranged: `y > x` and `x > y` (the semantic meaning of the function, but we have achieved this from the definition of how the function works and we have reduced it to the pure mathematics which we can work with certain axioms for).

From `y > x` and `x > y`, you can rearrange as `x > x` and `y > y` (If x is greater than y, then it is greater than all things y is greater than. y is greater than x, therefore x is greater than x).

This is a logical contradiction, and therefore our assumption (that they were both true) is incorrect.

Therefore, by Proof by Contradiction, when x ≠ y, and x,y ≥ 0, the function `less` cannot return true for both less(x,y) and less(y,x).

(it's been a while since I had to do a proof (though I'm going to have to do some coming up so it is good practice) so I might be a bit rusty. If any one sees an error, please point it out and I will try to fix it)

Comment: Ok I see you are reducing the code symbol less to the mathematical symbol >, from math somehow you know that y > x and x > y is not possible. Actually I wanted to avoid this turn. Wouldn't it be possible to reason with the symbol less alone, and not regress to <. I have the feeling you were close before you added >.

Comment: Bit harder, and I don't know if this is logically sound (and I might be skirting the no > or < a little), but same assumption step as before. `less(x,y)` implies `less(0, x - y)`. `less(y,x)` implies `less(0, y - x)`. `(a-b) = -(b-a)`. If (x - y) is a natural number (greater than or equal to zero), then (y - x) is not (`(x-y) = -(y-x)` where `x-y` is defined to be a natural number.) or vice versa. This violates our assumptions, and therefore proof by contradiction. (It is a bit weak, but comment box limitations along with a bit of time since i've done such a proof... but I think it might work)

Comment: Also in my original proof I clarified how I know that `x > y` and `y > x` is a logical contradiction.

Comment: Actually I like your proof very much. Also the use of transitivity to show the contradiction is fine for me. But I want to have a selection of proofs on the ground that I want to see what is possible in proving the posed problem. So I am more addressing the general audience not to stop proposing additional proofs, to see the breadth of approaches. This is a little bit the problem with proofs, that the same thing can have different proofs!